# Admob to 6.4.1 dosnt work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, libgdx

I used google play services lib and this is my 
main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MyUnitID" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my manifest (Not sure if its really good..did alot of shit in there)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.noamro.bloo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

in the main.xml graphical layout i can see red box that say "Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing"
and i did set adSize...
I just want that when my game works there will be an ad in the menu state.
Please help

Comment: Have you added the java side of things to load the ad?

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

TO

```
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```

Otherwise the ad will not resize depending on screen size (unless that's what you wanted), and in the onCreate method of your java file add:

```
adView = new AdView(this);
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        //.addTestDevice("") - You'll find your device ID in the LogCat output starting with a # it is recommended that you have a test device but it's up to you
        .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```